# $! doesn't work on command line

Tags: bash, command-line, process, background-process

I am running the below *directly in bash command line prompt*:

```
$ PIDS= ;while read name; do (cd $name; npm install) & echo started install; PIDS+=($!); done < <(\ls); for pid in ${PIDS[@]}; do wait $pid; done;
```

And I get this:

```
-bash: !: event not found
```

I assume the `!` symbol is being used to do command history substitution instead of seeing "$!" as a variable first.

---

How do I get pid of last background process if running directly on bash command line?

Comment: Can you give us the true command line you used? This one has obvious syntax errors.

Comment: I corrected syntax problems. If you replace "npm install" with "echo npm install" and replace "$!" with a non-existent pid (like 293847293847) then it should run for you

Comment: I can't reproduce it with the command line you give. What is you version of `bash`?

Comment: [Don't parse`ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) -- try `for name in *` instead of `while read name ... < <(\ls)` -- if you want to limit the files to only directories do `for dir in */`

Comment: Also unable to reproduce; I changed `cd $name` to `cd .` and `npm install` to `sleep 5` and then touched some sample files; the command string ran as expected.

Comment: ` $ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.`. I wonder if older Bash and on a mac is problematic here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't been able to reproduce your problem with `bash` 4.3 and 4.4, so here is a generic answer.

Your problem is triggered by the `!` in `PIDS+=($!)`, `!` being the start of history substitution (which is enabled by default with an interactive shell).

Either disable history substitution with `set +H`, or quote the `!` (not desirable here because of the preceding `$`) or add a space after `!`. Bash manual reads:

> `!` Start a history substitution, except when followed by a blank,
>   newline, carriage return, `=` or `(` (when the extglob shell option is
>   enabled using the shopt builtin)

Your command line would then become:

```
PIDS=()
while read name; do
    (cd "$name"; npm install) &
    echo started install
    PIDS+=( $! )
done < <(\ls)
wait "${PIDS[@]}"
```

Notes:

- You are not limited to one line of code here
- I have added proper quotes around variables
- You can wait for several PIDs at once; I fixed that

Answer (score 1):

From the [bash changelog](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES):

> This document details the changes between this version, bash-4.2-alpha,
>   and the previous version, bash-4.1-release. (…)
>
> 3.  New Features in Bash (…)
>
> u.  History expansion no longer expands the `$!` variable expansion.

To cope with older versions of bash, change `PIDS+=($!)` to `PIDS+=($! )`. The extra space ensures that bash will never think that this `!` starts a history reference.